# Salt file.recurse filter include_pat: not working

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to copy few files which extension using `file.recurse` but when I put `include_pat: *.sh`, its throwing error:

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:test_copy_sqlautomation' failed: did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a simple issue of YAML not recognizing `*` as a glob character. And Salt is expecting an alphabetic or numeric character to match `include_pat`. If you wrap it with quotes it should work.

Example:

```yaml
copy_shell_scripts:
  file.recurse:
    - name: /tmp/scripts
    - source: salt://scripts
    - include_pat: "*.sh"
```